# How to return variable from Fragment on back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have sections and subsections in database(sections and subsections stored in one table).
Section examples:A - transport, B - animals.
Subsection example in A: car, bicycle. in B: cat, dog.
I have one fragment which displays items in gridView. On item click I want to open same fragment but with other data. I have variable in table that shows if item is subsection or not. I transfer this variable in bundle when I create fragment. But when I press back button I have variable same as on previous fragment.

The question is how to transfer this variable on back press?

The illustration how I have:[image]

The illustration how I want:[image]

This is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_services_section, container, false);

        final DBHelp dbHelp = new DBHelp(getActivity());

        final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int connectionId = bundle.getInt("connection_id");  

//if connectionId == 0 it means that this section doesnt have subsection
//number in connectionId show us with which section is connection other section
//for example 
//section: Animal with id 1.
//section: Cat with id 2 and connectionId 1 means that this section is subsection of section with id = 1  

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Integer.toString(connectionId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        sectionsArrayList = dbHelp.readSectionsFromDatabase(connectionId);

        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gv_services_section);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_service_section);

        sectionGridAdapter = new SectionGridAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_section_service_layout, sectionsArrayList);
        gridView.setAdapter(sectionGridAdapter);


        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                int id = sectionsArrayList.get(i).getId();  

//when we press on item we get this item id
//and transfer it to next fragment
//so when we create new section in it in connection id we will put int id  

                Fragment ServicesFragment = new ServicesFragment();
                bundle.putInt("connection_id", id);
                ServicesFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, ServicesFragment );
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Your `Activity` can have an `onBackPressed()` method where you can do whatever you want when the back button is pressed.

Comment: but I don't have activity, its a fragment

Comment: `Fragment`s are always inside `Activity`s. Or a `DialogFragment` is created by an `Activity`.

Comment: You should create an interface declaring a method expecting your argument. Make your fragment implement this interface.
Call the method by accessing the fragment in `onBackPressed()` from your activity.

Comment: You mean that I should use ```onBackPressed()``` method in MainActivity? but it works only if I close my app on back button. It doesnt work when I press back button when I am on fragment

Comment: Where I should write my interface? If I open same fragment.

Comment: _"it works only if I close my app on back button."_ If you override the `onBackPressed()` button then the app isn't closed unless you close it yourself by code. _"Where I should write my interface?"_ In the `Fragment` that should receive and event/data from the `Activity`. _"If I open same fragment."_ In that `Fragment` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was saying in the comments section, you should override `onBackPressed()`, make sure to remove the `super.onBackPressed()` method call in it to prevent the activity to be killed.

Also, I recommend you to use an interface to abstract interactions between your Activities and your Fragments

`BackableFragment.java`

```
public interface BackableFragment {
    void onBack(String arg);
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(fragment instanceof BackableFragment) {
            ((BackableFragment) fragment).onBack("foo bar");
        }
    }
}
```

`MainFragment.java`

```
class MainFragment extends Fragment implements BackableFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_services_section, container, false);
        display("hello world");
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBack(String arg) {
        display(arg);
    }

    private void display(String arg) {
        // ...
    }
}
```